# Express nested set difference in terms of unions and intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking at proving this: $$A - (B-C) = (A-B)  ∪ (A ∩ B ∩ C)$$

Pictorially this makes sense. However in constructing my proof I am not getting the desired result.

$$(B - C) = B ∩ C^c$$  Note: $C^c$ is $C$ complement

Then, $$A - (B - C) = A ∩ (B^C ∩ (C^C)^C) = A ∩ (B^c ∩ C) $$

From this I see that $x$ will be in $A$ and $C$ but not $B$. I am unsure of where I am making a mistake but further progress with this leads me to an incorrect statement.

I keep getting $(A−B)−C=A−(B∪C). $

Comment: What do you mean by $B-C$? I am unfamiliar with that notation.

Comment: @Dasherman $B - C$ is usually alternative notation for $B \setminus C$, the complement.

Comment: @mrp Ah, of course, thank you. I have seen that before, I don't know why I didn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left side:

$B-C=\{b\in B \mid b\notin C\}$

$A-(B-C)=\{a\in A \mid a\notin (B-C)\}=\{a\in A\mid a\notin B \lor a\in C\}$

Right side:

$A-B=\{a\in A\mid a\notin B\}$

$A\cap B\cap C=\{a\in A\mid a\in B \wedge a\in C\}$

$(A-B)\cup (A\cap B\cap C)=\{a\in A\mid a\notin B\lor (a\in B \wedge a\in C)\}=\{a\in A\mid a\notin B\lor a\in C\}$

Thus left and right side are equal.

Comment: Could you explain the | and ∧ notation you use. Sorry, I am not familiar with it

Comment: | denotes the condition for the elements in the set. $X=\{x\in A\mid x\notin B \}$ means that X is the set of all elements in A that are not in B. $\wedge$ means 'and', $\lor$ means 'or'.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is $A-(B-C)=A \cap (B \cap C^c)^c $, not A - (B - C) = A ∩ (B^C ∩ C^C^C) .

Answer (score 0):

if $x \in A-(B-C)$ then $x \in A$ and $x \notin B-C$ which means either $x \notin B$ or $x \in B \cap C$.

Now if $x \notin B$ then $x \in A-B$ and if $x \in B \cap C$ then $x \in A \cap B \cap C$.
And in any case $x \in (A-B) \cup (A \cap B \cap C)$

We showed that $A-(B-C) \subseteq (A-B) \cup (A \cap B \cap C)$ and similarly you should prove the other direction to get the equality.